# Using categorical data for histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, kernel-density

Couldn't find the answer elsewhere.

Background:

I have data from the Business Dynamics Survey, a dataset that aggregates information on firms by firms' characteristics. I am trying to approximate the firms size distribution.
Now, the data features 10 firm size categories, the corresponding amount of firms in that category, and the level of employment. Sample:

[image]

For the life of me I can't figure out how to transform that into an histogram to perform a kernel estimation. A quick look to the docs didn't yield any useful info, because honestly I don't really know what I am looking for. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org) can be very fitting for such visualizations.
You want to use a [KDE plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) here.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello future internet person who's landed here. Two similar ways to approach it. Either

```
sns.displot(x=list(df.fsize), weights=list(df.firms), discrete=True)
```

Or

```
sns.catplot(x='fsize', y = 'firms', kind = "point",data = df).
```

To better characterize the underlying density I'm following this paper:
https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0081175018782579#_i11

Good luck on your journey!